# Docker and cron environments

Tags: bash, docker, cron, centos

I have problem with environment variables in docker image..
I created file: /cron.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

whoami
export
```

When I run manual in console: sh /cron.sh is OK (root, full envs) but when I add command to cron that I getting: root, basic envs (not have my variables).

Crontab -e:

```
* * * * *  /bin/bash /cron.sh > /proc/$(cat /var/run/crond.pid)/fd/1 2>&1
```

Why are the differences?

Comment: How are you setting up your container? What does your `Dockerfile` look like?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/YZD6068Y

Comment: You should really add that information to the question. Also, the Dockerfile you've shown has neither a CMD or ENTRYPOINT. How are you starting cron?

Comment: in entrypoint: exec crond -n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solution..

before run "exec crond -n" in entrypoint I save environments to file.

```
export > /.env
```

Next in cron add:

```
* * * * *  source /.env; /bin/bash /cron.sh > /proc/$(cat /var/run/crond.pid)/fd/1 2>&1
```

I hope I helped :-)